# Reusable SwiftUI Picker view

Tags: swift, picker

I am trying to create a reusable picker and am stumped with getting the foreach loop to function correctly.

I am getting two Errors

- Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'String' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
- No exact matches in call to initializer

  ```
    struct PickerSlector: View {
    var title: String
    @Binding var selection: String
    @Binding var item: String

    init(_ title: String, selection: Binding<String>, item: Binding<String>){
        self.title = title
        self._selection = selection
        self._item = item
    }


    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $selection){
            ForEach (item, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .font(Font.custom(Design.PrimaryFont, size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(selection == "Select" ? Color(Design.TextDark!) : Color(Design.accent!))
    }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ForEach` is trying to iterate over a `String`, while it should iterate over an array (or some kind of sequence, here I use an array to show how it can work).

Replace `item: String` with `items: [String]` and correct the rest of the code:

```
struct PickerSelector: View {      // <- Correct typo in Slector
    var title: String
    @Binding var selection: String
    @Binding var items: [String]      // <- Change here
    
    init(_ title: String, selection: Binding<String>, items: Binding<[String]>){      // <- Correct the initializer
        self.title = title
        self._selection = selection
        self._items = items      // <- More appropriate variable name
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $selection){
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {      // <- Update variable name here
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .font(Font.custom(Design.PrimaryFont, size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(selection == "Select" ? Color(Design.TextDark!) : Color(Design.accent!))
    }
}
```